# Web forms wrong redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When session expires and user should be redirected to login page, application builds wrong path to redirection

Page url: `site.com/dir/page.aspx`

Expected url for redirection: `site.com/security/login.aspx`

Real url: `site.com/dir/security/login.aspx`

In my `web.config` there is next code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/security/login.aspx" timeout="120" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

Why so and how to fix it?

There are no additional code in application events in `global.asax`. Application builds this path itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to below,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/security/login.aspx" timeout="120" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```